# navigation params get undefied

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

So i try to send some dummy data to the screen Profile

What i already try:
i already make so that it doens't have any @Types just send, the screen still did not get any data
usually with out declare any @types the data send.

and i already try delete ProfileStackScreen and just use Profile in MainNavigator, the data send. but how can i use the ProfileStackScreen so it won't have to use MainNavigator

here is my Code:

@Types

```
interface ProfileParams {
  name: string;
  body: {
    age: number;
    number: number;
    like: string;
    dislike: string;
  };
}

export type ProfileStackParamList = {
  ProfileScreen: { userInfo: ProfileParams };    
};
```

and i also make custome Component that only need name and onPress

```
<UserCard
        name={dataUser.name}
        onPress={() =>
          nav.navigate("ProfileScreen", {
            userInfo: dataUser,
          })
        }
      />
```

does the error because of the route? if you asking can you go to the screen, yes you can but when params the send data got undefiend

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
          headerTintColor: "#FFF",
          headerStyle: {
            shadowOpacity: 0,
            backgroundColor: "red",
          },
          headerBackTitle: "Back",
        }}
      >
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="Main"
          options={{
            title: "Main",
            headerShown: false,
          }}
          component={MainNavigator}
        />
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="Auth"
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          component={AuthStackScreen}
        />
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="ProfileScreen"
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          component={ProfileStackScreen}
        />
      </MainStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

ProfileStackScreen

```
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator<ProfileStackParamList>();
const ProfileStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ navigation }) => renderOptions(navigation)}
    >
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={Profile} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```